# Apache Superset troubles with MySQL JSON field

Tags: mysql, json, apache-superset

I have a MySQL database with records containing a JSON type field. An example of JSON type field is

```
{....
"callAttributes": {"teamId": "Red", "operatorId": "White", "customerPhoneNumber": "06123456"}
....}
```

Using Apache Superset version 3.0.2 I created a dashboard with pie chart and a cloud chart to display record suddivision by various operators.

At first the display is correct
[initial dashboard show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uj1gb.png)
and the query present in the dataset used is this

```
select 
CAST(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(iridevoice_bi.speech.doc, '$.callAttributes.teamId')) AS NCHAR) as Team, 
CAST(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(iridevoice_bi.speech.doc, '$.callAttributes.operatorId')) AS NCHAR) as Agent
from iridevoice_bi.speech 
where JSON_EXTRACT(iridevoice_bi.speech.doc, '$.callAttributes.operatorId') is not null AND
JSON_EXTRACT(iridevoice_bi.speech.doc, '$.callAttributes.teamId') is not null
```

but when I try to do cross filtering by selecting an operator (i.e. an Agent), superset "whitens" the cloud chart because it generates a where clause whith "impossible" conditions.

```
SELECT `Agent` AS `Agent`,
       count(`Agent`) AS `COUNT(Agent)`
FROM
  (select CAST(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(iridevoice_bi.speech.doc, '$.callAttributes.teamId')) AS NCHAR) as Team,
          CAST(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(iridevoice_bi.speech.doc, '$.callAttributes.operatorId')) AS NCHAR) as Agent
   from iridevoice_bi.speech
   where JSON_EXTRACT(iridevoice_bi.speech.doc, '$.callAttributes.operatorId') is not null
     AND JSON_EXTRACT(iridevoice_bi.speech.doc, '$.callAttributes.teamId') is not null) AS virtual_table
**WHERE `Agent` IS NULL
  OR `Agent` IN (NULL)
  AND (1 != 1)**
GROUP BY `Agent`
LIMIT 100;
```

Could it be a bug? Anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Aside: `JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(col, "path"))` can be simplified to `col-->"path"`. See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-inline-path)

Comment: `AGENT IN (NULL)` can never be true. `IN` uses `=` for comparison, and nothing is ever equal to `NULL`.

Comment: Why do you think you need that `OR Agent IN (NULL)` condition?

Comment: `COUNT(Agent)` only counts the non-null values of `Agent`. If you're only selecting `WHERE Agent IS NULL`, the count will always be 0. You want `COUNT(*)`. And there's no need for `GROUP BY Agent` if you're only selecting a single value of `Agent`.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution to my problem: just replace JSON_EXTRACT with JSON_VALUE in the query and superset turns into a good boy :) It no longer puts impossible conditions in the where clause and the cross filtering is perfect

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).